# How do I represent the boxed Double in pure Scala?

Tags: scala, autoboxing

In Scala there are 2 representations of double-precision numbers, one is an `AnyVal`, the other `AnyRef`. On the JVM they are mapped to the primitive `double` and the class `java.lang.Double` respectively.

Now what happens on platforms other than the JVM? I can use `Scala.Double` for the primitive, but how do I specify that I want a reference to the boxed Double without specifying `java.lang.Double`?

---

[Context - left to make sense of Thomasz' answer, but not the fundamental issue.

I have a Double that I want to inject with Spring into a Wicket component:

```
class MyPanel(id: String) extends Panel(id) {
  @SpringBean(name="rxAlarmLimitDb") var alarmLimitDb: Double = _
```

If I specify the type as `scala.Double` as above, the injector fails, as it can only inject Objects.

If I specify `java.lang.Double` as the type of the field, all is well

```
class MyPanel(id: String) extends Panel(id) {
  @SpringBean(name="rxAlarmLimitDb") var alarmLimitDb: java.lang.Double = _
```

But I'm trying to reduce my dependance on falling back on the Java API, so how do I represent the boxed `Double` without it?
]

Comment: My guess is that the boxed double *is* `java.lang.Double` -- just like Scala uses Java classes for a lot of other things (AnyRef = java.lang.Object, String = java.lang.String). I don't know for sure, though.

Comment: Those statements are true on the JVM. On the CLR there are different mappings, and I want to know how to represent boxed Double on either.

Comment: @Duncan can you put that as part of the question then? Or even better create a new one. Because running Spring on the CLR will have it's own issues.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clear(er) that this is not a question about Spring but rather the Scala type system.

Answer (score 11):

`scala.Double` == `double` in Java. When you box a `scala.Double`, it becomes a `java.lang.Double`.

```
scala> val f = 45d;
f: Double = 45.0

scala> println("f=" + f.getClass)
f=double

scala> def foo(d: Any) = println("d=" + d.getClass)
foo: (d: Any)Unit

scala> foo(f)
d=class java.lang.Double
```

There isn't any way of creating an object of type `scala.Double`. It's just an alias for double. So for your problem, you need to use a `java.lang.Double`, or enclose it in your own type and provide implicit conversions.

This definition makes sense if you think about it. All of the interaction between java & scala code which requires autoboxing & unboxing will work as expected.

If it makes a difference, you can always do:

```
type BoxedDouble = java.lang.Double
```

then you won't have to see the java.lang :-)

Comment: All these statements are true on the JVM, but Scala targets other environments.

Comment: From my POV the last section about creating a type alias solves @DuncanMcGregor's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating a bean of type `scala.Double`? Terrible but seems like it's working:

```
<bean id="rxAlarmLimitDb" class="scala.Double" factory-method="unbox">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.lang.Double">
            <constructor-arg value="4.2"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I suppose that my problem is solved with java.Lang.Double - but I'm curious!